# functionally modifying typedef string in c, references, pointers,

Tags: c

So, I'm brand spanking new to C. C# does garbage collection for me, so i don't need to worry about this stuff usually. This is causing me a days worth of problems, and I'm not finding any real example code where **passing references and pointers as arguments** is clearly exlained.

I also understand that passing things by value is considered poor practice, but I can't even grasp the concept of passing and referencing things in the first place.

Stated Goal: set value of a type defined string in another function, without a typed function, or any return values.

Any elementary explanation of **passing pointers and references functionally** would be helpful. The "Programming in C" book says to do something like this:

```
swap(int *a, int *b){
  //swap
}

//main
int a, b;
swap(&a,&b);
```

And if it could be done using some semblance of my code sample?

Thanks so much in advance!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//yes I'm aware that I need to set the array size
//to be larger than string length + 1 to account for "\0"
//this is a contrived, overly simplistic example for the sake
// of hopefully getting a very clear basic example

typedef char * string;

void func2(string *str){ 
  str = "blah"
  //currently, my code here does not change the value of str
  //as declared in main
  //have tried multiple different formats
  //i.e. func2(&str)
  //func2(str)
  //func2(*str)
  //etc
  //*str in this context I thought should be a pointer to the value of str passed from func
  //or perhaps str should be... not exactly sure what is going on and why 
  //this is so difficult
}
void func(string *str){
  str = "blah blah";
  //also trying
  //*str = "blah"
  //under the impression that this is now a char *** type? or char ** type?
  //in my code, str may be passed to a func2(str); 
  //where it may be manipulated again
  //it is my understanding that passing func2(&str) would
  //pass in the address of a pointer, which I don't want
  //or passing func2(*str) would pass a pointer to a pointer
  // which i also don't want.
}

main(){
   string str;
   //pass location of str in memory
   funct(&str);

   //this code will print the str set in func, but not when modified in func2
   printf("%s", str);
}
```

Comment: Your edit added nothing to the quality of your question and was frankly off-topic. Although I find it surprising that you can't find *any* tutorials about passing around pointers in C on the internet.

Comment: Not that I can't find any, but they're extremely implementation specific and difficult to follow. Asking for an explanation. This reaction is so typical of asking novice questions on stack overflow, because really, even the programming in C book implementation isn't boiled down to specifically passing pointers, it convolutes the matter by trying to explain a handful of other things at the very introduction of pointers and references. So I'm asking for a basic explanation of what is happening so I can debug this type of thing on my own.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point about tutorials being "implementation specific". Surely you could find one in standard C? But ultimately, the reason you're getting this reaction on SO is because you have the wrong idea about what SO should be. A question such as yours ("how do I use pointers?") is too broad to be answered here. Pointers are a vast subject and questions should have a specific direction on this site. It's not a place to have code explained to you. You should take the tour and visit [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what's on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making minimal modifications to your code, you might want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char * string;

void func2(string *str){
    *str = "blah";
}

void func1(string *str){ 
    func2(str);
}

int main(){
    string str;

    func1(&str);
    puts(str);

    func2(&str);
    puts(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested okay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'm asking specifically for an explanation to what is happening and why these other methods are necessary. and func2 is being called from func1, not from main. If I call my func2 from main, everything works fine, but when I call from func1, the value of string str never changes.

Comment: Okay, not sure what your code was trying to do. If you use `*str` to assign, then pointer types will at least match.

Comment: so my example is completely stripped to core functionality surrounding my problem.

basic flow, main initializes application, app has a notification to user. App accepts user input, switch on input, if input is invalid, notify, else call func2, in func2 notify with new value of successful input. So func2 needs to be called from func 1, since func 1 is the main application function

Comment: Your parameter str is a char** and is local to your function. Doing `str = "blah" ` you change the location pointed in memory of str but the types don't match and the modification is local. 
What you want to do is change the char* pointed by str, therefore you have to change the value pointer by your char** str by doing *str = "blah".

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge can you modify yimin's example here so I can follow what you mean?

Comment: Have revised, now func1 calls func2. Output for both is "blah". Suggest if you're trying to wrap your head around pointers and references, maybe try working with simpler types like `int`s. A pointer indicates where in memory a variable is. If you pass a pointer, then the function can modify the memory pointed by the pointer. It's very low level, and if you've been in C# or Java a long time, the paradigm shift can be daunting. Just start slow.